# find all possible words from a given query

Tags: java

I want to make a word search java program where whenever I enter a word that contains wild cards for example: b*t

I want to find all the possible words that fit that word from a text file that I have.

This is what I have done so far,

```
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a query: ");
    String input = cin.nextLine();

    try{
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if (input.length()==line.length()) {//show all letters in that range
               if ('*' != input.charAt(x)) {//check if letters contain '*'
                    if (line.charAt(x) == input.charAt(x)) {//check if letters match
                    System.out.print(line+"\n");//show all words that fit criteria
                }else{//skip letter
                   x=+1;
               }
                }else{//skip
                   x=+1;
               }
            }// end if
        }// end while

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can find all the words of certain length, I'm just struggling on finding the words that fit my query.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using [RegEx](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) ?

Comment: I tried doing that along with other ideas I tried to come up with. Obviously I wasn't implementing the right expression. And also, since the size of the word can change anytime, Also, I wasn't sure if whatever expression I put it, it wouldn't work for that length of a word. I'm not an expert on regex.

Comment: The regex that you are looking for is probably: /b.{1,}t/gi
use something like https://regex101.com/ to understand that regex and test it (and modify accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this fit your needs:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a query: ");
    String input = cin.nextLine();
    try{
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for(String w: words) {
                String p = "^" + input.replaceAll("\\*", ".*") + "$";
                if (w.matches(p)) {
                    System.out.println(w);
                }
            }
        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```